# if $2^{r}\equiv 1\pmod p$ show that $p\equiv\pm 1\pmod 8$

Tags: number-theory

Let $r$ is odd number,and $p$ is prime number,and such 
$$2^{r}\equiv 1\pmod p$$
show that
$$p\equiv\pm 1\pmod 8$$

I know if $p=8k\pm 1$,then I can prove $2^r\equiv 1\pmod p$,But In turn How prove

Comment: You can prove that if $p=8k\pm3$ then $2^r\not\equiv1\pmod{p}$, which is pretty straightforward. Any other value of $p$ is simply not prime, so you're done.

Comment: Exactly Barak Manos. Regards.